# Should I use a comma or a period?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> If that's the case, **Ben**. We suggest that
>   you contact our Answer Desk here for
>   further assistance: https://.

Is it wrong to use a period on this sentence after the name? Should a comma be used instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Questions like this require you show the research you've done before posting. It also requires a context for your sentence. What exactly are you trying to say? Without a context, it's impossible to know if it is correct. Please update the questions to avoid closure.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it wrong to use a period **in** this sentence after the name?

Yes, because it's not a complete sentence.

> Should a comma be used instead?

Yes, a comma is fine there. Then start the next phrase with a small *w*:   "...case, Ben, we suggest...".